Execution order of preload and script defer
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>preload and prefetch</title>
  <link rel="preload" href="./a.js" as="script" onload="console.log('a.js loaded')">
</head>

<body>

</body>
<script src="./a.js" defer></script>

</html>


// a.js
console.log("a");

According to the preload document, shouldn't script wait for the preload to complete before executing? Why did console. log ('a ') execute before the preload callback function onload

MDN "The load event fires once the [link] and all of its imported content has been loaded and parsed - so the js in the file runs first.  Couldn't find a definitive statement for rel=preload as=script whether "load"/"parse" means after it's executed, but that appears to be what's happening in practice.

Possibly off topic: defer essentially means "load now and run after body - putting a defer script after body is meaningless.

shouldn't script wait for the preload to complete - this statement makes me think you don't understand what rel=preload does.  There's no "wait for preload to complete" - it simply says "make a fetch for this file now, so when it's needed it's already been fetched" MDN

Related: how does preload work (SO)
